# "could not import <package> current file is not included in a workspace module" in VS Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am unable to import URL packages. Even after I have installed the package on my system using 'go get github...." and have ensured that they exist in their go.mod file, I am shown:

```
could not import <package> current file is not included in a workspace module
```

I remember just a few weeks ago I did not even have to run "go work init" in every single Golang Project directories on my system. But now I am asked to add these to workspace. Back then after I would install any package from my terminal, I would just have to import{} the installed package in the code and the code would work!

I am currently trying to create a project using on understanding ['ebitengine'](https://github.com/topics/ebitengine) and for that I ran the following commands

```
go mod init PROJECT (in the directory same as the code)
go work init
go get -u github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2
go mod init PROJECT (Again because the error was still being shown)
go work init (Again because the error was still being shown)
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with my system and why I am unable to import packages correctly.

The output of running 'go env' is:

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/user/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/user/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/user/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/user/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/user/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.2"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/user/Desktop/learnings/go/14SwitchCase/go.mod"
GOWORK="/home/user/Desktop/learnings/go/go.work"
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1152057857=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Similarly, my bashrc contains:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:$GOBIN
```

Please help me understand where I have gone wrong and why my VS Code is not working properly anymore.

Comment: Please read and follow go.dev/doc the Tutorials about how to set up go modules (which you _must_ use). If you need more help then: Please provide actionable information, e.g. exact commands executed, exact import stetments and content of go.mod file.

Comment: I have added the commands as suggested. As stated in the post, I used to be able to create programs using the mentioned method of mine, which is same as the one mentioned in the documents. I suspect that I have accidentally changed some system/go detail which I should not have.

Comment: The order of your commands makes no sense. There is no need for a workspace if you are developing as single module. You did not show how you import the package, nor how you build your code.

Comment: That's my exact point! I should not be asked to create a workspace if I am only working on a single file but VS Code keeps asking me to creating one over and over again.

Comment: Just don't create a workspace. Not doing smth. is not really complicated. And stop using an IDE for this type of work.

Comment: I just created a new directory and created go.mod, ran ''go get -u github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2" and now I am shown "file is within module "snek", which is not included in your workspace. To fix this problem, you can add a go.work file that uses this directory." - This is what happens when I don't add go.work and chances are even after that, this won't work. There is only a single go code in the entire directory too...

Comment: I just created a go,work in the parent directory and voila, the code is working properly now and the packages have been imported.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. There is no need for a workspace here, I just tried it out. Note that you probably should not go get dependencies _before_ you have some code.

Comment: But if I don't add a workspace, then I am unable to run the code as VS Code says "this module isn't part of your workspace". This happens even if I am only creating a single code in the directory.

Comment: @user21819272: it sounds like vscode has some concept of "workspace" internally, which is unrelated to [go workspaces](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces). Ignore go workspaces until you need to develop multiple different modules together locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the wrong GOPATH & GOROOT in my ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc file.

I replaced the existing GOPATH & GOROOT with the following lines and the issue was resolved:

> export GOPATH=$HOME/go
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin

Answer (score 3):

When you're working with multiple services in one Go workspace, please make sure to add your services in `go.work` file.

### Example

```bash
go 1.18

use( 
    .
    ./frontend
    ./auth
)
```

If not added you might get the Broken Import Error (For me it's in VSCode)

```bash
could not import auth/data (current file is not included in a workspace module)
```